# Building 'ni' on ubuntu 10.10 and diamondback - can't find my libusb?

Tags: ros, libusb, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been following along with the wiki: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ni

I've got diamondback, and my libusb is 1.0.8:

```
$ aptitude show libusb-1.0-0-dev
Package: libusb-1.0-0-dev                
State: installed
Version: 2:1.0.8-2
```

When I do "rosmake ni --rosdep-install" I get these errors:

```
Failed to find rosdep libusb1.0 for package ps_engine on OS:ubuntu version:10.10
Failed to find rosdep libusb1.0 for package openni_camera on OS:ubuntu version:10.10
Failed to find rosdep libusb1.0 for package openni_tracker on OS:ubuntu version:10.10
Failed to find rosdep libusb1.0 for package openni on OS:ubuntu version:10.10
Failed to find rosdep libusb1.0 for package nite on OS:ubuntu version:10.10
Failed to find rosdep libusb1.0 for package openni_pcl on OS:ubuntu version:10.10
WARNING: Rosdeps [u'libusb1.0', u'libusb1.0', u'libusb1.0', u'libusb1.0', u'libusb1.0', u'libusb1.0'] could not be resolved
```

And then it dies on:

```
Linking CXX executable ../bin/openni_viewer
  /home/murph/src/robos/ros-workspace/ni/openni_camera/lib/libopenni_driver.so: undefined reference to `usb_close'
  /home/murph/src/robos/ros-workspace/ni/openni_camera/lib/libopenni_driver.so: undefined reference to `usb_find_devices'
  /home/murph/src/robos/ros-workspace/ni/openni_camera/lib/libopenni_driver.so: undefined reference to `usb_open'
  /home/murph/src/robos/ros-workspace/ni/openni_camera/lib/libopenni_driver.so: undefined reference to `usb_find_busses'
  /home/murph/src/robos/ros-workspace/ni/openni_camera/lib/libopenni_driver.so: undefined reference to `usb_get_string_simple'
  /home/murph/src/robos/ros-workspace/ni/openni_camera/lib/libopenni_driver.so: undefined reference to `usb_init'
  /home/murph/src/robos/ros-workspace/ni/openni_camera/lib/libopenni_driver.so: undefined reference to `usb_busses'
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any clue what I missed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9194/building-%27ni%27-on-ubuntu-10.10-and-diamondback---can%27t-find-my-libusb?/) by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1033 on 2011-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was a missing export of -lusb in the openni_camera.  I've patched it in the master branch of ni.

commit f79573351876695203dae7a9680cf8449a5ab17b
Author: Tully Foote tfoote@willowgarage.com
Date:   Thu Feb 24 11:25:08 2011 -0800

```
missing export
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1